# Make a plot for specific x-axis values and mark with * (x,y) values in the plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

l would like to get my plot with x-axis values following only c values, such that c=[0.000001,0.00001,0.0001,0.001,0.01,1.0].

In other way. l would like to show the **y** value for each **c** .

Then mark in the plot the (c,y) values with * or squares.

Here is what l tried :

```
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
penalty_param=[]
lin_svm=[]
lin_svm_train=[]
for c in (0.000001,0.00001,0.0001,0.001,0.01,1.0):
   penalty_param.append(c)
   clf = LinearSVC(C=c)
   clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
   lin_svm.append(clf.score(X_test,y_test))
   lin_svm_train.append(clf.score(X_train,y_train))


fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots()
ax2.set_xslim((0.000001,0.00001,0.0001,0.001,0.01,1.0))
ax2.plot(penalty_param,lin_svm,label='Test accuracy',marker='o')
ax2.plot(penalty_param,lin_svm_train,label='Train accuracy ',marker='*')
ax2.set_xlabel(" C : penalty parameter")
ax2.set_ylabel("Accuracy")
ax2.legend(loc='best')
ax2.set_title(' Linear SVM classifier accuracy in terms of C parameter')
fig2.show()
```

l got the following : 
[image]

What is wrong with my code ?

**EDIT-1**
[image]

Comment: You did not ask matplotlib to use a marker.

Comment: @Goyo, please see my update.  To see the markers of these values (0.000001,0.00001,0.0001,0.001,0.01,1.0) l need to have x-axis values : 0.000001,0.00001,0.0001,0.001,0.011.0 in this scale  and not 0, 0.2 , 0.4 ,0.8 ..  This is my question

Comment: The markers seem to be at the specified x locations. I am not sure what you want. Changing the x ticks? Logarithm scale? A draft of the expected result would help.

Comment: Indeed they are at the specified locations. However, to show them clearly l need to change the x ticks in a way to see in the x-axis 0.000001,0.00001,0.0001,0.001,0.01,1.0 and not 0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0 .8, 1.0

Comment: You can [set the x ticks](http://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticks.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticks) and [labels](http://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels.html#matplotlib-axes-axes-set-xticklabels) and [scale the x axis](http://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xscale.html#matplotlib-axes-axes-set-xscale) at will.

Comment: Thank you it works

Answer (score 0):

```
ax2.set_xscale(value='log')
```

l just added this line of code. It allows to make x-axis scale varies in a log way rather than in a linear way